# django UpdateView for auth_user

Tags: django

I created my own `get_object` method to initialize an update-form with data from `self.request.user`.

The following code gives me all fields of `auth_user` instead of just `username` and `email`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
  model = User
  fields = ['username', 'email']

  def get_object(self):
     return get_object_or_404(self.model, pk=self.request.user.id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `fields` attribute [isn't supported in Django < v1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.fields). Instead, provide a custom ModelForm:

```
# forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm


class UserUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']


# views.py
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserUpdateForm

    # Parameters should match your superclass's parameters or have *args and **kwargs
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, pk=self.request.user.pk)
```